# C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a program which uses a DLL called spreadsheetgear.dll

In Visual Studio C# I do the following:

```
Reference the spreadsheetgear.dll
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook1 =
    SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook("C:\text.xls");
```

This works fine in C# with Visual Studio

In Powershell, I create the analogous logic by:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\spreadsheetgear.dll"
$workbook1 = New-Object SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook("c:\test.xls")
```

However Powershell gives me an error saying ....
New-Object : Cannot find type [SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

What am I doing wrong ... please assist.

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification - Is this powershell 1 or 2?  [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile was required back in 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not creating a new-object - you are calling a static method. Try:

```
 [SpreadsheetGear.Factory]::GetWorkbook("c:\test.xls")
```

`GetWorkbook` is actually a method on the `SpreadsheetGear.Factory` type - the error message is quite correct.